# WCF Response Time Spikes

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF Service with out of the box HTTP binding. It accepts a data object on which it runs some calculations and then returns the object.

A single call takes around 1.5s and works without issues. However concurrent calls can cause huge spikes in the completion time (10 concurrent calls can take up to 60s). Even if I run multiple calls one after the other I see spikes where the time taken jumps from 1.5 to over 5 seconds.

I currently have the service configured to single context mode and multiple concurrency mode. But I have tried other combinations to no avail.

Would anyone be able to provide a possible reason for these seemingly random spikes?

Thanks

Comment: We will need more details on `It accepts a data object on which it runs some calculations and then returns the object.` What calculations? Are you using any external resources such as a file stream? How big is this data?

Comment: post the code inside the service.

Comment: We would need the code; but you could follow the `Async` concept.  Which will allow the client / server to be handled on multiple threads.

Comment: I'm unable to post to code inside the service. The only external resource are numbers loaded into an array from a database the first time the service is called. I've ran the code locally (not as a WCF) and have not seen any problems. So I'm fairly certain it has to do with the setup of the WCF service itself.

Comment: As an experiment, I just removed the calculation from the service. So that all that no work is actually being done by the service. And I'm still seeing the spikes (of around 5 seconds) in response times.

Comment: Have you tried an Async design pattern for the service; to ensure that the server is threading all incoming / outgoing request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by a database read being performed on each call when it was only required to be done once.

I added a check to ensure the database read was only performed if the data hadn't already been loaded and this resolved the issue.